# java error: constructor in class cannot be applied

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class WaterHeater{

    public double Kilowatts;
    public double Water;
    public double Joules;
    public double Temp;
    public double Jkg;
    public double Energy;
    public double Time;

  //Constructor method

  public WaterHeater (double Water, double Kilowatts, double Joules, double Temp, double Jkg)  {

    this.Water = Water;
    this.Kilowatts = Kilowatts;
    this.Joules = Joules;
    this.Temp = Temp;
    this.Jkg = Jkg;
  }

    //Accessor for Kilowatts
    public double Kilowatts(){
    return Kilowatts;
    }

    //Accessor for Water
    public double Water(){
    return Water;
    }

    //Method for Energy used
    public double Energy(){
    Energy = Water*Jkg*Temp;
    return Energy;
    }

    //Method for Time to boil
    public double Time(){
    Time = Energy/Kilowatts;
    return Time;
    }
    }

//Test class

 public class Kettle extends WaterHeater{

  public static void main( String args[] ) 
  {

    WaterHeater Kettle = new WaterHeater(1, 2, 3600, 70, 4200); 

    System.out.println("\nWater: " +Kettle.Water + " L" +
    "\nKilowatts: " + Kettle.Kilowatts + " KW"+
    "\nEnergy used: " +Kettle.Energy() + " J" +
    "\nTime to boil: " +Kettle.Time() + " Seconds");


  }

}
```

Error: Constructor WaterHeater in class WaterHeater cannot be applied to given types.
       required: double,double,double,double,double
       found: no arguments 
       reason: actual and formal arqument lists differ in length

Comment: This is just a code dump. What is your question?

Comment: Learn Java coding standards.  You're following .NET/C# conventions.  Lower case class members, please.

Comment: Kettle won't compile because the default no-arg constructor is not publically accessible on WaterHeater which it extends.

Comment: @pbabcdefp please move that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of conventions wrong with the code but the problem with you code you are trying to run is this needs adding to the Kettle class

```
public Kettle(double Water, double Kilowatts, double Joules, double Temp, double Jkg) {
    super(Water, Kilowatts, Joules, Temp, Jkg);     
}
```

**Additional pointers**

Use camelcase/lowercase for attributes along with private instead of public

```
public double Kilowatts;
public double Water;
public double Joules;
public double Temp;
public double Jkg;
public double Energy;
public double Time;
```

should be

```
private double kilowatts;
private double water;
private double joules;
private double temp;
private double jkg;
private double energy;
private double time;
```

Use [Accessors and Mutators](http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm).

```
public double Kilowatts() {
    return Kilowatts;
}
```

should be

```
public double getKilowatts() {
    return kilowatts;
}
public void setKilowatts(final String kilowatts) {
    this.kilowatts = kilowatts;
}
```

The main class would also look like this

```
public class Kettle extends WaterHeater {

    public Kettle(double water, double kilowatts, double joules, double temp, double jkg) {
        super(water, kilowatts, joules, temp, jkg);     
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        WaterHeater kettle = new WaterHeater(1, 2, 3600, 70, 4200);

        System.out.println("\nWater: " + kettle.getWater() + " L" + "\nKilowatts: " + kettle.getKilowatts() + " KW" + "\nEnergy used: " + kettle.getEnergy() + " J"
            + "\nTime to boil: " + kettle.getTime() + " Seconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After adding the constructor to the Kettle class it worked. I will also make these changes. What does super does?

Thanks!!

Comment: When extending a class like you have done with `Kettle extends WaterHeater` it calls the constructor in that extended class

Comment: After running the program did not return any values (1,2,3600,70,4200). Any help?

Comment: got it. I had to set the default values in the waterheater class.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have written a constructor in `WaterHeater`, you cannot extend `WaterHeater` without writing a constructor for `Kettle` that calls the `WaterHeater` constructor. You can do that as follows:

```
public Kettle(double water, double kilowatts, double joules, double temp, double jkg) {
    super(water, kilowatts, joules, temp, jkg);
}
```

If, on the other hand, you just want `Kettle` to be a class that tests `WaterHeater` then you just need to remove the words `extends WaterHeater`.

Comment: Thankyou it works! Is there other ways of creating constructors? (so they dont have to be written for other classes when using extends)

Also what does super does? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Using `Kettle` as a variable name *and* the name of the `class` is not going to work well.

A useful convention (and one that is followed by Java programmers) is to use camelCase for variable names (note the lower case c) and CamelCase for class names.

So keep the class name as it is but rename the variable:

```
WaterHeater kettle = new WaterHeater(...
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion but doesn't explain the cause of the error.

Comment: minus one? If you think I've missed something then let me know.

Comment: My thinking is that the opening sentence is sufficient. Don't want to get too grammatical given the OP is probably just starting out.

Comment: Sure. `WaterHeater` class constructor is not fulfilled by `Kettle` class, thus compiler error.

Comment: Check the upvoted answers to recognize the error. The compiler won't really get confused about the name of the variable being the same as the name of the class.